# Replace/Modify values in logical vector (Pattern Matching)

Tags: r

The question looks simple but I didn't figure out how it can done in R.
I want to modify a logical vector depending on patterns of its values. There are two modification steps:

1. If there is a single FALSE surrounded by TRUE values, switch it to TRUE.
2. If there are less then 3 successive TRUE values, switch them to FALSE.

Everything else should remain as it is. Here's an example:

```
# input  
x = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)

# output
xo = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
   TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)
```

`cbind(x,xo)` is

```
          x    xo
 [1,] FALSE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE FALSE
 [3,] FALSE FALSE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE
 [5,]  TRUE FALSE
 [6,]  TRUE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE
 [9,]  TRUE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE
[11,]  TRUE  TRUE
[12,] FALSE  TRUE
[13,]  TRUE  TRUE
[14,]  TRUE  TRUE
[15,] FALSE FALSE
[16,] FALSE FALSE
[17,]  TRUE  TRUE
[18,]  TRUE  TRUE
[19,]  TRUE  TRUE
[20,]  TRUE  TRUE
[21,] FALSE FALSE
```

I dont want to use a for loop because its slow and I would have to do a lot of if statements.

Is there a better way to get this working?

Comment: This is a general problem that seems to come up a lot on r-SO---applying, in a vectorized rather than looped-way, operations on a vector/matrix where the function to apply to one element depends on other elements identified by indexes, so it's not just a simple use of the apply family of functions or something.  I'm not enough of an R ninja to write a tutorial on how to do this myself, but someone oughta...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach:

```
#sample data 
x <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE,
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE, FALSE)
```

First, find the indices where FALSE values need to be changed to TRUE values, by looking for FALSE values that follow and are followed by TRUE values

```
tochange <- 
  intersect(
    intersect(
     which(x == FALSE),   # not strictly necessary
     which(diff(x) == 1)  # FALSEs followed by a TRUE
     ),
    which(diff(x) == -1) + 1 # FALSEs that follow a TRUE
    )
```

Change the values

```
x[tochange] <- TRUE
```

Next, look for runs of TRUE (and FALSE) that are less than 3 in length, and set  them to FALSE.

```
xrle <- rle(x)

xrle$values[xrle$lengths < 3] <-  FALSE

newx <- inverse.rle(xrle) # thanks to Frank for pointing out inverse.rle!

# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
#[10]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
#[19]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks! That's a really beautiful solution. Works perfectly. I will have to learn a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can try `rle` (thanks to @Frank for the modification)

```
xtmp <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x),{
    n    <- length(values)
    values[lengths == 1 & !values & ! seq_len(n) %in% c(1,n)] <- TRUE
}))

res <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(xtmp),
    values[lengths < 3 & values] <- FALSE
))

identical(xo,res) # TRUE
```

Comment: @plafort The credit goes to Frank for modifying it.  I liked your take on `regex`

Comment: @plafort It's not for here.  I was trying to replace some values in a column with sql command. Not getting it right.  I'll try to figure it out.  Thanks.

Comment: I had a hard time pulling the first instance of my regex match. It seems to be buried deep into `gregexpr` output with the mess of attributes. Do you know a quicker way?

Comment: @plafort Wouldn't just `as.numeric(ans[[1]])+1L` works for you?

Comment: It does work. I was led astray by the bloated output of `ans`. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
make_true <- function(x) {
  string <- paste(as.numeric(x), collapse='')
  ans <- gregexpr('(?=(101))', string, perl=T)
  x[as.numeric(ans[[1]])+1L] <- TRUE
  res <- rle(x)
  res$values[res$lengths < 3] <- FALSE
  inverse.rle(res)
}
```

The function takes advantage of the fact that T and F can be coerced to numeric. The pattern searched for is "101".

Comment: Also a really nice way. Thanks so much!